# Correct arguments in code, wrong argument when compiling

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Well I'm having a lot of fun today. I'm having an issue with a game engine I'm developing.

The issue is a little complicated to explain and it has to do with the way javascript works, but bear with me. Here is the current code:

```js
'use strict';
//------------------- LOW LEVEL ENGINE DEFINITIONS ------------------------//
kd.A.down(function(){
 if (gameobjects.length>0)
 gameobjects.forEach(function(o,i)
     {
      gameobjects[i].keydown_A(i);
     })
})

kd.D.down(function(){
 if (gameobjects.length>0)
 gameobjects.forEach(function(o,i)
     {
      gameobjects[i].keydown_D(i);
     })
})

kd.W.down(function(){
 if (gameobjects.length>0)
 gameobjects.forEach(function(o,i)
     {
      gameobjects[i].keydown_W(i);
     })
})

kd.S.down(function(){
 if (gameobjects.length>0)
 gameobjects.forEach(function(o,i)
     {
      gameobjects[i].keydown_S(i);
     })
})

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(){
 if (gameobjects.length>0)
 gameobjects.forEach(function(o,i){
  //var i=0; i<gameobjects.length; i++
  gameobjects[i].click_lm(i);
 })

 console.log(JSON.stringify(gameobjects))
}, true); 

var gameobjects=[];

var stdobj={
 x:0,
 y:0,
 id:0,
 create:function(){},
 destroy:function(){},
 step:function(){},
 keydown_A:function(){},
 keydown_D:function(){},
 keydown_W:function(){},
 keydown_S:function(){},
 click_lm:function(){},
 click_rm:function(){},
 draw:function(){}
};

var mpos={x:0,y:0}

$("body").mousemove(function(e) {
    mpos.x = e.pageX;
    mpos.y = e.pageY;
})

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 if (canvas.getContext) 
 {
     var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }

var main=function(){
 //instance_create(oRoomMng,0,0)

 drawscr();
}



function detectmob() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}
window.onresize = function(event) {
resizeDiv();
}


function resizeDiv() {
 var vpw = $(window).width();
 var vph = $(window).height();


 var m=detectmob()

 if (m)
 {

 }
}

//------------------------------ MID LEVEL ENGINE -------------------------//
function drawscr(){
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 800)

 kd.tick();

 if (gameobjects.length>0)
 gameobjects.forEach(function(o,i)
 {
  gameobjects[i].draw(i);
 })

 if (gameobjects.length>0)
 gameobjects.forEach(function(o,i)
 {
  gameobjects[i].step(i);
 })

 requestAnimationFrame(drawscr);
}

$(document).ready(main)
$(document).ready(resizeDiv)

function lengthdir(dis, dir)
{
 var xspd=Math.cos(dir) * spd 
 var yspd=Math.sin(dir) * spd

 return {x:xp, y:yp}
}

function instance_create(obj,x,y)
{
 //console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

 var l=gameobjects.length;
 gameobjects.push(obj)

 gameobjects[l].x=x
 gameobjects[l].y=y

 gameobjects[l].id=l

 gameobjects[l].create(l);

 return l;
}

function instance_destroy(id)
{
 gameobjects[id].destroy(id);

 gameobjects[id]=stdobj;
}

function dtr(inp)
{
 return ((inp*Math.PI)/180)
}

function angle_difference(x,y)
{
 x=dtr(x)
 y=dtr(y)
 var res=Math.atan2(Math.sin(x-y), Math.cos(x-y))
 res=res*180/Math.PI
 return res
}

function point_distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)
{
 return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x2,2)+Math.pow(y1-y2,2)))
}

function point_direction(x1,y1,x2,y2)
{
 return (Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI);
}

function draw_sprite(sprite, x,y, angle)
{
 var ang=dtr(angle);

 var width = sprite.width;
 var height = sprite.height;

 ctx.translate(x, y);
 ctx.rotate(ang);
 ctx.drawImage(sprite, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
 ctx.rotate(-ang);
 ctx.translate(-x, -y);
}
//--------------------- SPRITE DEFINITIONS ----------------------------------//
var sShip=new Image();
sShip.src="spr_ship.png"

//--------------------- OBJECT DEFINITIONS ----------------------------------//
//room manager object

var oBullet=stdobj;
oBullet.step=function(id){
 gameobjects[id].y-=10

 if (gameobjects[id].y<0)
 {
  instance_destroy(id)
 }
};

var oShip=stdobj
oShip.name="Ship"
oShip.create=function(id){
 gameobjects[id].xspd=0;
 //instance_create(oBullet,gameobjects[id].x,gameobjects[id].y)
};
oShip.step=function(id){
 if (Math.abs(gameobjects[id].xspd)>0)
 {
  gameobjects[id].x+=gameobjects[id].xspd
 }

 if (Math.abs(gameobjects[id].yspd)>0)
 {
  gameobjects[id].y+=gameobjects[id].yspd
 }

 gameobjects[id].xspd=gameobjects[id].xspd*.9;
 gameobjects[id].yspd=gameobjects[id].yspd*.9;
};
oShip.keydown_A=function(id){
 gameobjects[id].xspd=-5
};
oShip.keydown_D=function(id){
 gameobjects[id].xspd=5
};

oShip.keydown_W=function(id){
 gameobjects[id].yspd=-5
};
oShip.keydown_S=function(id){
 gameobjects[id].yspd=5
};
oShip.click_lm=function(id){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(oBullet))
 instance_create(oBullet,gameobjects[id].x,gameobjects[id].y)
}

oShip.draw=function(id){
 draw_sprite(sShip,gameobjects[id].x,gameobjects[id].y,0)
};



//create room manager... THE VERY LAST THING THAT HAPPENS OK!?!?
instance_create(oShip,400,700)
```

so when I attempt to fire a bullet with space, instead of creating a bullet, all the elements of the array gameobjects are being overwritten by the **spaceship** object.

The issue seems to be coming from the oBullet creation (line 209) because a console.log of it immediately is returning the incorrect bullet object.

And none of this explains why the instance_create code is overwriting all of the gameobjects.

I can't figure out what's going on and it's driving me nuts. Can anyone help?

Comment: What is `stdobj`?  Assigning a reference to an object from one variable to another does not cause a new object to be constructed.

Comment: stdobj is an object defined earlier... pastebin line 41-56 or something. I had the impression this would instantiate a new object. What should I do instead?

Comment: You should start by turning on [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) – all your `i` variables are undeclared. Then start using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of `for in` to iterate over arrays.

Comment: Stdobj is just an object. If you want more than one then you have to make more than one. You might want to take a step back and figure out some basics before jumping into a game engine, which brings on its own set of challenges apart from language basics.

Comment: @Ryan as you recommended, I turned on strict mode, declared all of my variables including I's, then I switched to forEach and now I'm getting a persistent "cannot read property 'draw' of undefined". I'm about to dive into debugging, but if you could point me in the general direction It'd be helpful.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the advice, however it'd be best if I instantiated stdobj. How would I duplicate it for use in others? I'd assumed that was the standard way. As for giving up, that's kind of a bad way to figure out a language. I've been working at javascript for a year now and I've never taken a serious look at objects and methods. I can't do it alone but I'm sure not giving up that easy!

Comment: I didn't say give up. I said take a step back: I don't see how you've used JS for a year and not looked at objects and methods, it's kind of what JS is built on. What I said, and am saying, is that you need to understand the environment in which you're working, and it's generally easier to do that in a domain more simple than a game engine, e.g., do some JS OO tutorials that ignore game engine complexity, then come back. You'll come back wiser and it should only take a few hours, days at the most. There's a reasons masters continue to practice the fundamentals even after they're masters.

Comment: @Ryan  I'm an idiot and didn't read the forEach docs well enough. Problem solved. However the main issue still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
var stdobj={
    x:0,
    y:0,
    id:0,
    create:function(){},
    destroy:function(){},
    step:function(){},
    keydown_A:function(){},
    keydown_D:function(){},
    keydown_W:function(){},
    keydown_S:function(){},
    click_lm:function(){},
    click_rm:function(){},
    draw:function(){}
};
```

From your source, creates a single object, and you're reusing that for every variable.

The simplest direct patch to that code would be to make a function, EG:

```
function stdobj() {
    return { x:0, y:0, ... }
}
```

And call `stdobj()` each time you use it, rather than just `stdobj`

That way it creates a new object for each time you need it.

Comment: Yup, I implemented this and it works perfectly. Thanks a bunch man!